# common lisp's let binds, not executes?

Tags: common-lisp

In this code

```
(defun foo ()
   . . .
   (let ((bar (foo)))
      (if bar
         . . .)))
```

in the `let` line, `let` is only binding, right? It doesn't actually run `foo`. I assume `foo` is run (recursively) for the first time in the `if` statement, correct? If what I assume is correct, is there a way to have `let` actually execute `foo` and then assign the results to `bar`?

Comment: `LET` executes `(foo)` and binds the value to `bar`.

Comment: Parentheses is application, but you could only harvest the function object like this instead without executing: `(let ((foo #'+)) (funcall foo 1 2)) ; ==> 3`. BTW: your code is an infinite loop. It is sure to fail on all CL implementations.

Comment: @Sylwester Well... There COULD be a conditional hiding in the elided code between `defun` and `let` and be passing state in globals...

Comment: @Vatine If the yadda is affecting the code in question it should have been included. If you ever see what you described it's best to rewrite the whole thing so it could be readable and predictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an answer that shows an example that illustrates the behavior of **let**.  However, an example via an implementation doesn't answer conclusively whether it's *supposed* to behave that way, or whether implementations are free to do different things, or whether there's a bug in the implementation.  To know what's supposed to happen, you need to check the documentation.  Fortunately, the Common Lisp HyperSpec is freely available online.  The documentation for **let** says:

> #### [Special Operator LET, LET*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm)
>
> let and let* create new variable bindings and execute a series of
>   forms that use these bindings. let performs the bindings in parallel
>   and let* does them sequentially.
>
> The form
>
> ```
>  (let ((var1 init-form-1)
>        (var2 init-form-2)
>        ...
>        (varm init-form-m))
>    declaration1
>    declaration2
>    ...
>    declarationp
>    form1
>    form2
>    ...
>    formn)
> ```
>
> first evaluates the expressions init-form-1, init-form-2, and so on,
>   in that order, saving the resulting values. Then all of the variables
>   varj are bound to the corresponding values; each binding is lexical
>   unless there is a special declaration to the contrary. The expressions
>   formk are then evaluated in order; the values of all but the last are
>   discarded (that is, the body of a let is an implicit progn).

Thus, all the forms are evaluated (executed), then the results are bound the values, and then the forms in the body are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you provided, `foo` is evaluated and then assigned to `bar`. You can test this by simply evaluating something like:

```
(let ((foo (+ 1 2)))
  (if (= foo 3)
      foo
      nil))
; => 3
```

cf. [PCL: Syntax and Semantics](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#special-operators) or [Lispdoc](http://lispdoc.com/?q=let&search=Basic+search).

### Edit

As @paulo-madeira brought up in the comments, this is not enough to test, since you don't know when each one was evaluated. See his comment for a way to test it using `FORMAT`. Anyway, the takeaway is, the `LET` you propose evaluates `foo` and assigns it to `bar`, which means your function `foo` is defined in terms of itself, which means you're up to no good.

Comment: Actually, that's not enough to test this.  You must have observable side effects, such as `(defun foo ()
  (format t "enter let~%")
  (let ((x (foo)))
    (format t "enter when~%")
    (when x
      #| ... |#)
    (format t "leave when~%"))
  (format t "leave let~%"))`.